# Combing matched keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

*Edited*
I get the combined item_ids now, but not the single item_ids.

I have an array with three keys.

```
$searchArray = { 
[0]=> array(3) {
      ["keyword"]=> string(7) "history" 
      ["url"]=> string(7) "history" 
      ["item_id"]=> string(2) "16" 
}  
[1]=> array(3) {
      ["keyword"]=> string(4) "past"
      ["url"]=> string(4) "past" 
      ["item_id"]=> string(2) "16" 
}
[89]=> array(3) {
     ["keyword"]=> string(10) "biomedical" 
     ["url"]=> string(10) "biomedical" 
     ["item_id"]=> string(2) "34" 
} 
[93]=> array(3) { 
     ["keyword"]=> string(10) "biomedical" 
     ["url"]=> string(10) "biomedical" 
     ["item_id"]=> string(2) "35" 
}
```

I want to combine the options that have the same keyword/url.

Just need to check if keyword matches.

The final format needs to be something that jquery autocomplete can accept, where I can assign the text to keyword and the value to url, id to the item_id.

There were only two keys in the array before and I would combine matches this way.

```
  foreach ($searchArray as $row)
  {  
       $combineMatches[ $row['keyword'] ][] = $row['item_id'];        
  }
```

result after using `json_encode()`:

```
"anthropologist":["27","37"],  
"biomedical":["34","35"],  
"m.s.":["18","19","23"]
```

What I currently have:

```
$combineMatches = array();    
foreach ($searchArray as $row)
{         
     $match = 
 array_search($row['keyword'],array_column($combineMatches,'keyword'));
     if($match){
        $combineMatches[$match]['item_id']+= $row['item_id'];
     }else{
        array_push($combineMatches, [
           'keyword' => $row['keyword'],
           'url' => $row['url'],
          'item_id' => array_push($row['item_id'])
       ]);      
     }    
 }
```

#### Result:

```
[7]=> array(3)
{    
    ["keyword"]=> string(8) "theology"   
    ["url"]=> string(8) "theology"   
    ["item_id"]=> NULL   
}   
[13]=> array(3) 
{  
    ["keyword"]=> string(7) "writing"   
    ["url"]=> string(7) "writing"   
    ["item_id"]=> NULL   
}
```

How do I add to the array column of just item_id ? Which I see is a string, but I need as an array.

This gets JSON encoded in the end of the PHP and read by jquery autocomplete.

Comment: The variable names of your arrays and statements don't match up so it's hard to keep track of what you're working with and what's contained in the last foreach loop's `$row`.

Comment: `item_id` are string - you cannot add them with "+" - use concat PHP operator `.` as:   `$combineMatches[$match]['item_id'] .= " " . $row['item_id'];` or use `[]` to add as array: `$combineMatches[$match]['item_id'][] =  $row['item_id'];`

Comment: sorry finalArray & combineMatches are the same array really, I just renamed it to combineMatches later when the third key was added.

Comment: @dWinder still does not work, after json_encode I get wrong format.

Comment: @hpgodwin if you solved your own question, post your answer and mark it as accepted, otherwise this question lives (incorrectly) as unanswered forever.

Comment: The solution never belongs in the question, so I've rolled back your last edit. As parttimeturtle says, if you've solved the problem yourself, please post an answer explaining the solution. [It's fine to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). But we maintain a very strict separation between questions and answers here, as discussed in the [tour].

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the proper format! My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing out the string/array issue.
I changed how to add to the third key if there is a match, and if there isn't a match the solution was changing the array_push to just array.

```
$combineMatches = array();
foreach ($searchArray as $row)
{
   $match=array_search($row['keyword'],array_column($combineMatches,'keyword'));
   if($match){
      $combineMatches[$match]['item_id'][] = $row['item_id'];
   }else{

        array_push($combineMatches, [
           'keyword' => $row['keyword'],
           'url' => $row['url'],
          'item_id' => array($row['item_id'])
       ]);

   }    
}
```

Comment: Glad you figure it out